# Is there a way to put focus on target element when I'm using #elemend_id as href in anchor element?

Tags: html, css

Like, if I have  navbar with links to to elements on same page. If one of the anchor element has  `<a href = "#div_1">show me div 1 </a>`, and `<div id = "div_1"> Lorem Ipsum</div>` gets focus

Comment: What do you want the focus for? It is possible, but there may be a better way to do what you want.

Comment: for technical documentation simple webpage, there is nav menu with indexes for different content, I want to focus, or do with some more nice way stand out the content I clicked for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To focus a div you need it to have a tabindex, using -1 means that it can be focused with JS but wont get focus from the tab key.

```html
<a href = "#div_1" onclick="document.getElementById('div_1').focus()">show me div 1 </a>
<div id = "div_1" tabindex="-1"> Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

Comment: Added an example

Comment: That seems decent way, is there one without javascript? Just for interest

Answer (score 1):

> I want to focus, or do with some more nice way stand out the content I clicked for.

There a way to make the content "stand out" without focusing it. This may also improve accessibility and requires no JavaScript.

Use the `:target` CSS pseudo-class:

```css
p:target {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a href="#something">Go to something</a>
<p id="something">I'm something</p>
```